Image size not changing in ppt slide in python
I'm copying the Excel chart and pasting it into PowerPoint as a image, adjusting the image's size. However, there is a problem: every image on the slide is the same size and size is changing in the new slide. Please correct me if I made a mistake here.
Is it due to lock aspect ratio in powerpoint? if so how can i disable it through python

    import win32com.client 
import yaml 
import os
#from win32com.client import constants

#Read Yaml file
with open(r"C:\Users\anavs\Anavarathan\Chart\config.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    data_loaded = yaml.safe_load(stream)
# Grab the Active Instance of Excel.
ExcelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = True

# Grab the workbook with the charts.
xlWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\anavs\Anavarathan\Chart\Test.xlsx')

# Create a new instance of PowerPoint and make sure it's visible.
PPTApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
PPTApp.Visible = True

# Add a presentation to the PowerPoint Application, returns a Presentation Object.
PPTPresentation = PPTApp.Presentations.Add()
PPTPresentation.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\anavs\Anavarathan\Chart\output.pptx")
# Loop through each Worksheet.
PSlideNumber = 0
for xlWorksheet in xlWorkbook.Worksheets:

    # Grab the ChartObjects Collection for each sheet.
    xlCharts = xlWorksheet.ChartObjects()

    # Loop through each Chart in the ChartObjects Collection.

    for index, xlChart in enumerate(xlCharts):
        SlideNumber = data_loaded[f"Chart{index+1}"].get('Slide')

        # Each chart needs to be on it's own slide, so at this point create a new slide.
        if SlideNumber != PSlideNumber:
            PSlideNumber = SlideNumber
            PPTSlide = PPTPresentation.Slides.Add(Index=SlideNumber, Layout=12)  # 12 is a blank layout
        # Display something to the user.
        print('Exporting Chart {} from Worksheet {}'.format(xlChart.Name, xlWorksheet.Name))

        # Copy the chart.
        xlChart.Copy()

        # Paste the Object to the Slide
        # PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType=1)
        ### Paste chart and resize either as a scaled from original or specific values
        #img = PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(constants.ppPasteShape) 
        img = PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType=1) 
        STop = data_loaded[f"Chart{index+1}"].get('Top')
        SLeft = data_loaded[f"Chart{index+1}"].get('Left') 
        SWidth = data_loaded[f"Chart{index+1}"].get('Width')
        SHeigth = data_loaded[f"Chart{index+1}"].get('Heigth')
        print(SlideNumber,STop,SLeft,SWidth,SHeigth)        
        ### Scaled
        #img.ScaleWidth(1, 1)
        #img.ScaleHeight(1, 1)
        ### Set Specific Size
        img.Width = SWidth
        img.Height = SHeigth
        ### Also set position of the image in the slide
        img.Left = SLeft
        img.Top = STop
    # Save the presentation.
PPTPresentation.Save()
ExcelApp.Quit()
PPTApp.Quit()
os.system("taskkill /f /im excel.exe")
os.system("taskkill /f /im powerpnt.exe")```

**config.yaml**
```Chart1: 
    Slide: 1
    Top: 50
    Left: 50
    Width: 210
    Heigth: 210
Chart2: 
    Slide: 1
    Top: 50
    Left: 480
    Width: 210
    Heigth: 210
Chart3: 
    Slide: 1
    Top: 270
    Left: 50
    Width: 210
    Heigth: 210
Chart4: 
    Slide: 1
    Top: 270
    Left: 480
    Width: 310
    Heigth: 210
Chart5: 
    Slide: 2
    Top: 50
    Left: 50
    Width: 230
    Heigth: 150
Chart6: 
    Slide: 2
    Top: 205
    Left: 50
    Width: 230
    Heigth: 150
Chart7: 
    Slide: 2
    Top: 360
    Left: 50
    Width: 230
    Heigth: 150
Chart8: 
    Slide: 2
    Top: 50
    Left: 400
    Width: 230
    Heigth: 150
Chart9: 
    Slide: 2
    Top: 205
    Left: 400
    Width: 300
    Heigth: 150


raise AttributeError(a)
AttributeError: ppPasteShape  i am getting this error

i am using pywin32                   307

its not pasting in image format.

upgraded to latest version pywin32 308. still getting the same error

Ah OK, so then, keep your code as is and after the line img = PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType=1)  just add img.LockAspectRatio = 0 to unlock the aspect ratio of the image.

please submit this in answer. ill vote for it.
